# postgresql pendant of SqlDependency / notify on query result changes

Tags: sql, postgresql, notifications

I have a postgresql database and I want to send E-Mail notifications if the results of specific queries have changed.

For SQL-Server there is a C# class called `SqlDependency` which allows me to do this in a very easy way. I'ts possible to say: "Hey notify me if `SELECT * FROM a WHERE d` changes".

But I couldn't find any solution for postgresql. I've often seen `NOTIFY`, but as far as I understand it, it's not as powerful as this SQL-Server mechanism, because I have to build lot of triggers. 
My additional problem is, that the queries can potentially be very complex :/

So: Has postgresql any mechanism for this scenario?

Comment: Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We just used hangfire to process the data frequently looking up the last changed time stamps in our tables.

Answer (score 1):

I recently also went into that problem,

I'm currently evaluating the listen/notify functionality of psql.
It seems the suiting thing, but you have to implement your db-observer your self.

[How to fire NOTIFICATION event in front end when table data gets changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471629/how-to-fire-notification-event-in-front-end-when-table-data-gets-changed)