# Change/Notification Event when PostgreSQL Data changed

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, triggers, notifications, npgsql

I am writing a desktop app in vb.net with visual studio 2019. I access a postgreSQL database with the NPGSQL provider.

To be able to react to changes in the database, I have set up a trigger according to these articles:

- [How to fire NOTIFICATION event in front end when table data gets changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471629/how-to-fire-notification-event-in-front-end-when-table-data-gets-changed)
- https://www.graymatterdeveloper.com/2019/12/02/listening-events-postgresql/

The function in PostgreSQL looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.NotifyOnDataChange()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$ 
DECLARE
    data JSON;
    notification JSON;
BEGIN
-- if we delete, then pass the old data
-- if we insert or update, pass the new data
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    data = row_to_json(OLD);
ELSE
    data = row_to_json(NEW);
END IF;

-- create json payload
-- note that here can be done projection 
notification = json_build_object(
        'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
        'action', TG_OP, -- can have value of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
        'data', data);  
        
-- note that channel name MUST be lowercase, otherwise pg_notify() won't work
PERFORM pg_notify('datachange', notification::TEXT);
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnDataChange
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
ON um_permission
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.NotifyOnDataChange();
```

And this is the vb.net code:

```
Private Sub Load
    Dim tConnectionString As String = String.Format("Password={0}; Username={1}; Database={2}; Host={3}; Port={4}", "pswd", "name", "db", "localhost", 5432)
    myConn.ConnectionString = tConnectionString
    myConn.Open()
    Dim tCom As NpgsqlCommand = myConn.CreateCommand
    tCom.CommandText = "LISTEN datachange;"
    tCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
    AddHandler gDatabaseEngine.TivanDatabase.Notification, AddressOf Database_Notification

    tCom.CommandText = "update um_permission set key='view' where id=1"
    tCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Private Sub Database_Notification(_sender As Object, _e As NotificationEventArgs, _table As String, _action As String)

    'Do something

End Sub
```

This all works great. The command *ExecuteNonQuery* triggers the event.

But my expectation is that every change to the table will trigger the event. However, if I make a change in pgAdmin or in another instance of my program, the event is **not** fired.

Is this due to a bug in my code or is this the usual behaviour? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds weird. Try adding a `RAISE NOTICE` to the trigger function and check if it is called.

Comment: I just started postgresql, so excuse my lack of knowledge. I added a RAISE NOTICE to the trigger function, and used the Query Tool in pgAdmin. Then the message appears, but the event in vb.net does not fire.

Comment: Good. Then there probably is a problem with the listening code.

Comment: I'm not a vb.net user, but I would assume that once your sub returns, the connection goes out of scope and so is no longer listening.

Comment: The point is, if i change the table from inside the vb.net application the event fires every time. And I get the information/payload as defined in the postgreSQL function. But only if I change the database from **inside** the application.